# Port is inactive in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino

[image]

In Arduino IDE the Port(Tools->Port) is inactive. I'm using Arduino Uno which was working properly. What should I do to fix this problem?
Also there is an error icon next to the name of Arduino Uno in windows Device Manager ( Error code in device manager: "This device cannot start. (Code 10)" ).
I uninstalled and updated the driver but nothing happened.
Any help will be appropriated!

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lj78KJxOsGA

Comment: Did you set an invalid baud rate at any point? I've had the same thing happen to me on Linux because of that. If this is the case, find `preferences.txt` (maybe it's in `c:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Arduino\preferences.txt (Windows Vista)`) and change the line `serial.debug_rate=xxxx` to `serial.debug_rate=9600`

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg It didn't worked!

Comment: @jDo No I didn't. in text file, serial.debug was 9600 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/esp8266-nodemcu-board-usb-driver-and-windows-10/702853). You basically need to download and install the CH340 USB driver.

I downloaded it from [this link](https://www.wch.cn/downloads/CH341SER_EXE.html) and it worked pretty well.